# How can I set the actual date as a min value to my lightning-input datepicker?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield, date-picker

I am trying to set the actual date (today) as a minimum value to my date picker, using LWC.
I can't make it work, as I get a component error message that "today is not defined".

HTML

```
<template>
 <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Reservation__c">
   <lightning-messages> </lightning-messages>
     <lightning-input-field 
        field-name="Date__c" 
        type="date" 
        name="Reservation__c" 
        label="Date field"
        min={today} 
        max="2024-01-01"> 
      </lightning-input-field>
     <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new">
    </lightning-button>
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

In the JS file:

```
@track today; 

 connectedCallback(){
      this.today = new Date();
      let yyyyMmDd = today.toISOString().slice(0,10);
 }
```

I don' know actually what to or how to set the `today` and use it as the min value (if it is possible).

Comment: There is no property like `min` on `lightning-input-field`. Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification

Comment: @Piotr Gajek Not documented there but it does work and is also referenced (and therefore supported, I'd say)) by SFDC in other documentation, e.g. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HlA6QAK

Comment: Oh. Nice, good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer above it looks the `min` property even if not documented should be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Try something like that:

```js
today; // track is not needed for primitive types

connectedCallback(){
   this.today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
}
```

If will not work, add also `if:true` to HTML so element will render when `today` will be set.

```html
<lightning-input-field 
        if:true={today}
        field-name="Date__c" 
        type="date" 
        name="Reservation__c" 
        label="Date field"
        min={today} 
        max="2024-01-01"> 
</lightning-input-field>
```